# tableView in collectionView IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uicollectionview

I'm using Collection View in a `MainStoryboard.storyboard` showing a grid of images. I want to go from collection view to table view when the item is selected, i.e on following method:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

How can I load tableView in collectionView's method after selecting?

**My approach:**

```
UIViewController *vc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"SubCategories" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SubCategories"];
 [self.view  addSubview:vc.view ];
```

Comment: You should perform a segue to your new scene, not add the view to the current view

Comment: please explain me in detail ho to perform that in collectionview's method? @Paulw11

Comment: Search for how to use `performSegueWithIdentifier`

Comment: Performing that action is a pretty basic thing on iOS. Try digging into the Documentation a bit more or checkout this tutorial. http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make a new ViewController in your Storyboard that has a TableView in it. Then add a segue from the first ViewController (from the VC itself, not from the CollectionView) to the new ViewController. Make sure you set a segue identifier for that segue.

Then in your didSelectItemAtIndexPath method, call

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourIdentifier" sender:self];
```

You can then implement the prepareForSegue method in your first VC to pass data about what was selected to your second VC.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Make sure your are about to perform the same segue
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"YourIdentifier"]) {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        SecondViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
        [vc setMyObjectHere:object];
    }
}
```

Note, don't ever call prepareForSegue, iOS calls it for you when a segue is about to happen.